# Incorrect image size on different screen size

Tags: android

I have a screen on which I need to display a number of images inside a horizontal LinearLayout.

I designed it for an xhdpi. I set the sizes of each ImageView to 100dp, and on an emulator (xhdpi 768x1280 4.7" screen) it looks something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if5G5.png) while on a tablet emulator (xhdpi 1534x2048 9" screen) it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtMiY.png).

In the latter, the images aren't scaled properly to look like it does on the smaller screen.

Is there a way to make it look the same on both screen sizes?

Comment: use `android_weight="1"` in all of your imageview and set your `android:width="0"` and fix your height.or just use `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make your layout adjust on different screen you need to design it to be responsive. Yes like what G.Dator said, you can use weight attribute. Here's the example :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know if you have further question.

Comment: Thanks! After checking the "adjustViewBounds" option, this actually gave me my desired output. I did notice that I have to set the height to some arbitrary large value to maximize the size of all the images, and then adjust them using the layout_margin properties.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the image is the same size in 2 devices. The problem is the difference between your `dp` width of your phone (`384dp`) and your tablet (`767dp`). There're few ways to resolve it:

1. using multiple layout files for sw360 and sw720. You can check this [Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
2. Using the same weight for all your `ImageView` with `adjustViewBound=true` to keep your image ratios.
3. Using code to set your `ImageView` size programmatically.

Comment: As far as I know – for the emulators, at least – both the phone and tablet are picking up the xhdpi resource file. To confirm this, I checked the value of the screen density for both virtual devices and they both returned the same value so solution #1 seems unuseful. I'll look further into the others.

Comment: @CodeAl are you sure? You should have 2 layout-sw360 and layout-sw720

Comment: Absolutely sure.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implementing a responsive layout structure (like what @Bhimbim mentioned), there is a library (https://github.com/intuit/sdp) which can be useful when you want to code once and use it on multiple different devices, it offers you `sdp` unit instead of `dp` which helps your view to scale better.

Example:

```
layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
```

(Sorry i couldn't comment as i have registered recently).